# Using twig inside theme folder rather than twig from modules

Tags: 8, theming

I installed a paragraph module and it uses twig from inside /modules/paragraphs/templates/
but I would like to override it inside my /theme/theme_name/ folder.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Edit:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
* paragraph--steps--default.html.twig
* paragraph--steps.html.twig
* paragraph--default.html.twig
x paragraph.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/paragraphs/templates/paragraph.html.twig' -->
```

Twig debug looks for the file in modules/paragraphs/templates and I would need it to look in mytheme/templates/. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy the mentioned module template over to your theme's template folder. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Create templates folder inside your theme and enable Twig debugging, [check here for how to enable twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374).

Once twig debugging enable look for theme suggestions and name the templates accordingly.

Comment: Please check edit in my main post.

Comment: Copy template file from paragraph module folder to the theme folder. Clear cache and reload page.

Comment: This answer is correct, to override a template you just need to copy the right suggestion name (that you want to use) into your theme in the `/templates` directory. Clear the cache, and Drupal will use that.